# Just using $+$ ,$-$, $\times$ using any given n-1 integers, can we make a number divisible by n? (NO bracket allowed!!)

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

Probably title is slightly ambiguous but I could not see any way of shortening the problem.

I am sure many of you have seen the problem like

$2$ $\square$ $2$ $\square$ $2$ $\square$ $2$ $\square$ $2$  $=$ $20$

something like this where between the numbers we can use some sort of operation depending on the question.

Well I think the question is motivated by this.

Let $n>2$. Given any set of $n-1$ numbers (we can swap the order) and we can only use addition, subtraction and multiplication, can we make a multiple of $n$ always?

Another way of putting it is:

Given $n-1$ elements of non-integral domain $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, can we make zero only using $+,-,\times$? Oh and by the way bracket is not allowed!!!!

I was asked this in an interview randomly and I could not figure it out and the interviewer did not know the answer either.

---

As people suggested I will post the 'proof' if bracket is allowed.

If bracket is allowed then this is easy. I will use the second form of the problem.

Firstly let $n>2$ and $a_1,...,a_{n-1} \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

If any of the $a_i$ is equal to zero then we could just multiply all the $a_i$s so assume $a_i$ are all non-zero.

Also if bracket is allowed, if $a_i=a_j$, we could simply put $(a_i-a_j)$ and multiply all other elements together.

So we could assume $a_1,...,a_{n-1}$=1,...,n-1

In which case if bracket is allowed, $(1+(n-1))$ times all other elements would give the wanted answer.

But hey. NO Brackets allowed!

I have checked for small $n$s that this is possible and my intuition is that for big $n$ this should easily be possible. But I can't think of a way to show that.

Comment: sorry the formatting is terrible. I have left maths world a few years ago so for got how to use LaTeX properly,

Comment: In the title, you say "a number dividing $n$" but in the text of the question you imply that you want a **multiple** of $n.$ Note that $5$ is a number dividing $10$ but $20$ is a multiple of $10.$

Comment: indeed. I will fix it

Comment: How would you make an even number with a single $1$ for the case $n=2$?

Comment: Just an observation, but for small $n$ it is feasible to check all the cases. An upper bound is $n!3^n$

Comment: I guess I should have specified $n>2$. I have manually checked it is possible for small numbers (upto n=6 I think?). For big n I feel that it should be possible very easily but again, no idea how I could prove that

Comment: I can confirm it is possible up to $n\le 10$, so far.

Comment: It seems that you never need to use all $3$ operations at once. (No exceptions up to $n\le 10$.)

Comment: @Vepir - I for one am quite interested in your (presumably computer based) results.  The OP's conjecture is fascinating enough, and your variant (no need to use all 3 ops) is even more unexpected!  So if you feel like posting an Answer maybe with code, I'd definitely upvote it.

Comment: @antkam Done. Btw, not only that, but we also do not need to swap the order if the numbers are sorted in decreasing order.

Comment: It seems that this is also true for a more generalized claim. Given a constant $k\in\mathbb Z$, there exists $n_k$ such that: For all $n\gt n_k$, given any set of $n-k$ numbers, we can always make a multiple of $n$ (using $-,+,\times$). Your claim is that $n_1=2$. For another example, it seems $n_2=5$, etc. I wonder if it is possible to prove any upper bound on $n_1$ (prove your claim for sufficiently large $n$).

Comment: @antkam If $n$ is prime, then the answer is yes. Either we have a $0$ in the set (and use multiplication), or we don't have a zero in the set which means we can use: [For any $n-1$ non-zero elements of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, we can make zero using $+,-$ if and only if $n$ is prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4094506/318073).

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the problem well. Is it  << use $n-1$ numbers from the set $(1,...,n-1)$ and operations $+,-,\times$ to make a number divisible by n? >> Thanks, in advance for clarifying!

Comment: I decided to cross-post this to [math overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/391476/88524).

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:** If $n\gt 5$, it seems we can make everything equal $0$ just using $\{-,\times\}$. That is, it seems $+$ is not needed! (*This was verified for $n=6,7,8,9,10,11,12$.*)

But, I do not know how to prove this.

---

---

*This is a long comment, [as requested](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4078978/just-using-times-using-any-given-n-1-integers-can-we-make-a-number#comment8439886_4078978).*

---

There are only $\binom{2n-3}{n-1}$ multisets $a_1,...,a_{n-1} \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ to consider, for given $n$.

We have $a_1,...,a_{n-1}\ne 0$, because otherwise we can multiply everything with $0$.

I have written a simple brute force search in python. I observed:

1. It seems we only need to use $2$ operations at once ($+,\times$ or $-,\times$ or $+,-$).
2. It seems we can always assume $a_1\ge a_2\ge \dots \ge a_{n-1}$.

These two observations have been verified for all $n\le12$.

---

Below is my (*disclaimer: inefficient*) python code and its output.

For all possible (*decreasing*) mutisets of numbers:

- It tries all $3\cdot 2^{n-2}$ ways to put two of three operations between numbers.
- If solution isn't found, it tries it again but for all permutations of numbers.
- If solution isn't found, it tries all $3^{n-2}$ ways to put three operations.
- If solution isn't found, it tries it again but for all permutations of numbers.
- If solution isn't found, it is a counter-example to the problem.

Code:

```
import itertools

def exprf(A,b,O):
    return ''.join([f'{A[_]}{O[b[_]]}' for _ in range(len(b))])+str(A[-1])

def solve(A,n,OP):
    k = len(OP[0])
    for o in range(k**(n-2)):
        b=[]
        while o!=0:
            o, r = divmod(o, k)
            b.append(r)
        while len(b)!=n-2:
            b.append(0)
        for op in OP:
            expr = exprf(A,b,op)
            if eval(expr)%n==0:
                return [expr, op]
    return False

for n in range(3,20):
    m = 0
    for a in itertools.combinations(range(1,2*(n-1)), n-1):
        m += 1
        A = [a[i]-i for i in range(n-2,-1,-1)]
        solved = solve(A, n, [['+','*'],['-','*'],['+','-']])
        if not solved:
            for P in itertools.permutations(A):
                solved = solve(P, n, [['+','*'],['-','*'],['+','-']])
                if solved:
                    break
            if not solved:
                solved = solve(A, n, [['*','+','-']])
                if not solved:
                    for P in itertools.permutations(A):
                        solved = solve(P, n, [['*','+','-']])
                        if solved:
                            break
                    if not solved:
                        print("COUNTER-EXAMPLE:", A)
                    else:
                      print(f"{n}: All operations and permutation needed:", solved[0])  
                else:
                    print(f"{n}: All operations needed:", solved[0])
            else:
                print(f"{n}: Permutation needed: ", solved[0])
        else:
            pass #print(solved[0])
    print(f'{n}: {m} multisets solved.')
```

Output:

```
3: 3 multisets solved.
4: 10 multisets solved.
5: 35 multisets solved.
6: 126 multisets solved.
7: 462 multisets solved.
8: 1716 multisets solved.
9: 6435 multisets solved.
10: 24310 multisets solved.
11: 92378 multisets solved.
12: 352716 multisets solved.
```

Btw, if "$\ge$" is changed to "$\le$" in observation 2., then

```
10: Permutation needed:  1*1*1*1*1*4*8-1-1
```

is the only observed exception to the modified observation.

Answer (score -2):

If $n=2k+1$, take

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i = \frac{n (n-1)}{2} = \frac{(2k+1) 2k}{2} = k (2k+1) = k n $$

which is divisible by $n$ .

If $n=2k$ and $n>4$, take

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} i = 2k \prod_{i=1,i \neq 2,k}^{n-1} = n\prod_{i=1,i \neq 2,k}^{n-1} i $$

which is divisible by $n$ .

Finally, for $n=4$, take

$$ 3-2-1 = 0 $$

which is divisible by 4.

Comment: No the question is that if we were given ARBITRARY $n-1$ numbers whether we can make multiple of $n$ using the explained operations.

Comment: You are right, I thought the problem was for the sequent numbers 1 to n-1.