# Which sets of $n-1$ non-multiples of $n$ can't make a multiple of $n$ using $+,-$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, recreational-mathematics, sumset

*This is a follow up to my previous question (see linked question).*

*In short, there it is shown that if $n$ is **prime**, then **any** set can make it.*

---

I want to characterize sets $\mathbb A_n$ of multisets $A$, such that the following claim holds:

> Let $n\gt 2$. For any multiset $A\not\in \mathbb A_n$ of $n-1$ non-zero elements of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, we can make zero using $+,-$.

Problem is finding all $A$ such that $A\in\mathbb A_n$.

Due to [Cauchy-Davenport theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_sumset#Cauchy%E2%80%93Davenport_theorem), we know that: [For any $n-1$ non-zero elements of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, we can make zero using $+,-$ if and only if $n$ is prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4094506/318073). Therefore, if $n$ is prime then $\mathbb A_n=\emptyset$.

It remains to consider composite $n$.

---

a) Let $n$ be **odd** composite. Let $p$ be a fixed prime factor of $n$.

> It seems that if $A$ consists of $n-2$ multiples of $p$ and one non-multiple of $p$, then $A\in\mathbb A_n$.

What other multisets $A$ satisfy $A\in\mathbb A_n$? I do not know of any other examples.

---

b) Let $n$ be **even** composite.

> If $A$ contains an odd number of odd integers, then clearly $A\in\mathbb A_n$.

What other multisets are also in $\mathbb A_n$?

Number of other multisets seems to be $1,2,27,32,1000\dots$ for $n=4,6,8,10,12,\dots$

For example, for $n=4$ and $n=6$ they are $\{2,2,2\}$ and $\{3, 3, 3, 3, 2\},\{3, 3, 3, 3, 4\}$.